# Can a switch statement take two arguments?

Tags: php

is it posible for a PHP switch statement to take 2 arguements? For example:

```
switch (firstVal, secondVal){

    case firstVal == "YN" && secondVal == "NN":
    thisDesc = "this is the outcome: YN and NN";
    break;

    case firstVal == "YY" && secondVal == "NN":
    thisDesc = "this is the outcome: YY and NN";
    break;
}
```

Many thanks, I haven't done PHP in years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but if your case is as simple as what you have, just concatenate the two inputs and test for the concatenated values:

```
switch ($firstval . $secondval) {
 case "YNNN": ...
 case "YYNN": ...
}
```

Comment: While is seems like a decent solution, both `$firstval` and `$secondval` would have to be of a predefined length or type. I guess  what I'm trying to say is that if the first one is "Y" and the second is "NNN" and in another case the first is "YN" and the second "NN", there's no way to tell them apart as the concatenated value will be "YNNN".

Comment: @Francois: You can introduce a separato to make sure, the values aren't mixed up. `$firstVal . '|' . $secondVal` and `case 'YN|NN'`/`case 'YY|NN'` (and so on).

Comment: I known, that's why I put the disclamer. But this can still work if you know a char that cannot be in either of those variables. Just stick that in between them. Doesn't scale well though, replacing with plain if/else blocks is probably better in the long run.

Comment: I like this solution but the dependence on knowing what the values are seems weird. Is that just a requirement of using switch statements?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't. A `switch`-statement like

```
switch ($a) {
  case 1:
  break;
  case 2:
  break;
}
```

which is effectively the same as

```
if ($a == 1) {
} else if ($a == 2) {
}
```

You can use a slightly different construction

```
switch (true) {
  case $firstVal == "YN" && $secondVal == "NN":
  break;
  case $firstVal == "YY" && $secondVal == "NN":
  break;
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (true == ($firstVal == "YN" && $secondVal == "NN")) {
} else if (true == ($firstVal == "YY" && $secondVal == "NN")) {
}
```

In some cases its much more readable instead of infinite `if-elseif-else`-chains.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but i think this answer is not covered here:

You can pass multiple arguments to an array and pass that as the argument to the switch:

```
switch([$fooBah, $bool]) {
            case ['foo', true]:
                ...
                break;
            case ['foo', false]:
            case ['bah', true]:
                ...
                break;
            case ['bah', false]:
                ...
                break;
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot do that, not only in PHP but any other programming language.

Answer (score -1):

i have the answer !
You can do that by remove the "break" instruction.
if you do

```php
$i = 2;
switch ($i) {
    case 1:
        echo "a";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'b';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'c';
        break;
    case 3:
        echo 'd';
        break;
}
```

Your script will stop at the first break. So the output is `b`.

Now, if you remove the break instruction, the switch will continue to the end and verify all.

```php
$i = 2;
switch ($i) {
    case 1:
        echo "a";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'b';
    case 2:
        echo 'c';
        break;
    case 3:
        echo 'd';
        break;
}
```

`Output : cb`
So you can do 2 conditionnal instruction like this :

```php
$i = 3;
switch ($i) {
    case 1:
        echo "a";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        echo 'd';
        break;
}
```

`Output: d`
Your computer will read the `case 2:` and the result it false, but there is no break instruction, so the computer will continue and read `case 3: >> True` and the result is true : the computer execute your instruction. :)

If you didn't understand my explanation, i own you to read the switch php manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php).